# Expand a row by click of table on a certain condition Ant Design table

Tags: reactjs, antd

I need the help of yours.

I need to write the code such that the table row should expand only when it's toggle is `on` when the toggle is `off` it should not expand. I have used the property `expandRowByClick` to expand a row when it is clicked. But I am not getting how to expand it only when the toggle is `on`. Please check the sandbox link and help me out. Thank you.

SandBox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-microservice-qd3ku?file=/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this with ternary operator

```
expandedRowRender={ this.state.firstRow ? record => this.handleRowRender(record):null }
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-thompson-vpjlk?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I need small modification in code, if possible please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62345611/expand-a-row-by-click-of-table-on-a-certain-condition-ant-design-table-react-js). Thank you. :)